# MySQL CASE statement and REGEXP

Tags: mysql, regex, case

I want to use a CASE statement that uses REGEXP. Currently I am doing something like this:

```
SELECT NAME,
 CASE INFO
   WHEN 'not cool' THEN 'Not Cool'
   WHEN 'very cool' THEN 'Cool'
 ELSE INFO
 END AS INFO
FROM INFO_TABLE
```

Is there any way to use REGEXP in the initial statement to make the condition act as a REGEXP? In theory this is what I want, which doesn't work:

```
SELECT NAME,    
 CASE INFO REGEXP
   WHEN 'not cool' THEN 'Not Cool'
   WHEN 'very cool' THEN 'Cool'
 ELSE INFO
 END AS INFO
FROM INFO_TABLE
```

I want 'not cool' and 'very cool' to be regular expressions. Hope that is clear enough.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try this

```
select name,
case
  when info regexp 'not cool' then 'Not Cool'
  when info regexp 'very cool' then 'Cool'  
else 
  info
end 
  as info
from INFO_TABLE;
```

Comment: Excellent, guess because I had the extra 'INFO' in there right after the case, I really got messed up!  +1

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is regex, but there are wilcards that you can use with LIKE.

The wildcard % gives you any number of characters. The wildcard _ gives you any single character.

Example:

```
SELECT email FROM people WHERE email LIKE '%harvard.edu'
```

Comment: MySQL has had REGEXP since at ~4.x: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: Oh, thanks. And I see Oracle just got regular expressions with the 10g release :-)