# SQL regex works the wrong way

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to build a SQL statement to retrieve user names in the following order

- at first, return the names that start with Arabic letter, then the names that start with English letters, then the names that start with special characters.
- then sort each of the three groups in ascending order.

This is my code:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `user` 
order by case when substring(name,1,1) like 'N[أ-ي]' then 1
              when substring(name,1,1) like '[a-zA-Z]' then 2
              else 3
              end
        ,name
```

The problem is that the case part always returns 3, and so the statement sorts the names in the default order(special chars first, then English letters then Arabic letters). What is the problem in my query?

Comment: @Cyval Thanks for your correction.But even when I changed the parameter the function still doesn't work.

Comment: nop, this article's example says the substring start index starts with 1... https://msdn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/library/ms187748.aspx and this too: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

Comment: @Cyval . . . You are simply wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use regex, not like... (because you use regular expression)

```
SELECT `name` FROM `user` 
order by case when substring(name,1,1) regexp 'N[أ-ي]' then 1
              when substring(name,1,1) regexp '[a-zA-Z]' then 2
              else 3
              end
        ,name
```

Reference: [MySQL CASE statement and REGEXP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755349/mysql-case-statement-and-regexp)